# Loss function for CNN is not decreased with time

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to solve image binary classification problem using Tensorflow and CNN. The problem is that loss function is not minimised during the training. So, did I correctly choose and implemented a loss function and CNN itself?  Here is logs of the training process:

```
11:33: step 0, accuracy = 0.21, loss = 12.23 (29.4 examples/sec; 8.718 sec/batch)
11:36: step 100, accuracy = 0.44, loss = 42.59 (159.5 examples/sec; 1.605 sec/batch)
11:39: step 200, accuracy = 0.68, loss = 72.22 (155.5 examples/sec; 1.646 sec/batch)
11:41: step 300, accuracy = 0.39, loss = 35.76 (157.0 examples/sec; 1.631 sec/batch)
11:44: step 400, accuracy = 0.54, loss = 55.42 (155.7 examples/sec; 1.644 sec/batch)
11:47: step 500, accuracy = 0.68, loss = 72.16 (152.5 examples/sec; 1.679 sec/batch)
11:50: step 600, accuracy = 0.34, loss = 29.44 (157.1 examples/sec; 1.629 sec/batch)
11:53: step 700, accuracy = 0.58, loss = 59.97 (152.9 examples/sec; 1.675 sec/batch)
11:55: step 800, accuracy = 0.65, loss = 68.29 (154.2 examples/sec; 1.660 sec/batch)
11:58: step 900, accuracy = 0.36, loss = 32.56 (155.0 examples/sec; 1.651 sec/batch)
12:01: step 1000, accuracy = 0.56, loss = 54.97 (150.0 examples/sec; 1.707 sec/batch)
12:04: step 1100, accuracy = 0.62, loss = 63.46 (155.3 examples/sec; 1.648 sec/batch)
12:06: step 1200, accuracy = 0.36, loss = 31.22 (154.3 examples/sec; 1.659 sec/batch)
12:09: step 1300, accuracy = 0.57, loss = 57.37 (154.7 examples/sec; 1.654 sec/batch)
12:12: step 1400, accuracy = 0.57, loss = 57.37 (154.9 examples/sec; 1.653 sec/batch)
12:15: step 1500, accuracy = 0.31, loss = 25.31 (151.1 examples/sec; 1.695 sec/batch)
12:17: step 1600, accuracy = 0.57, loss = 58.76 (154.5 examples/sec; 1.657 sec/batch)
12:20: step 1700, accuracy = 0.55, loss = 56.54 (157.2 examples/sec; 1.628 sec/batch)
12:23: step 1800, accuracy = 0.34, loss = 28.18 (156.3 examples/sec; 1.637 sec/batch)
12:26: step 1900, accuracy = 0.64, loss = 67.77 (155.4 examples/sec; 1.647 sec/batch)
12:28: step 2000, accuracy = 0.50, loss = 48.81 (157.1 examples/sec; 1.630 sec/batch)
12:31: step 2100, accuracy = 0.30, loss = 23.36 (158.2 examples/sec; 1.618 sec/batch)
12:34: step 2200, accuracy = 0.66, loss = 70.25 (156.4 examples/sec; 1.637 sec/batch)
12:37: step 2300, accuracy = 0.53, loss = 53.08 (157.0 examples/sec; 1.630 sec/batch)
12:39: step 2400, accuracy = 0.30, loss = 24.90 (156.5 examples/sec; 1.636 sec/batch)
12:42: step 2500, accuracy = 0.67, loss = 72.63 (158.5 examples/sec; 1.615 sec/batch)
12:45: step 2600, accuracy = 0.49, loss = 47.38 (156.5 examples/sec; 1.636 sec/batch)
12:48: step 2700, accuracy = 0.32, loss = 26.96 (155.3 examples/sec; 1.648 sec/batch)
12:50: step 2800, accuracy = 0.69, loss = 74.03 (157.8 examples/sec; 1.623 sec/batch)
12:53: step 2900, accuracy = 0.47, loss = 44.35 (157.3 examples/sec; 1.627 sec/batch)
12:56: step 3000, accuracy = 0.36, loss = 32.07 (159.3 examples/sec; 1.607 sec/batch)
12:58: step 3100, accuracy = 0.65, loss = 69.93 (159.2 examples/sec; 1.608 sec/batch)
13:01: step 3200, accuracy = 0.45, loss = 42.89 (158.9 examples/sec; 1.611 sec/batch)
13:04: step 3300, accuracy = 0.43, loss = 40.28 (157.5 examples/sec; 1.625 sec/batch)
13:07: step 3400, accuracy = 0.63, loss = 65.13 (156.6 examples/sec; 1.635 sec/batch)
13:09: step 3500, accuracy = 0.43, loss = 40.59 (157.6 examples/sec; 1.624 sec/batch)
13:12: step 3600, accuracy = 0.40, loss = 37.83 (157.1 examples/sec; 1.630 sec/batch)`
```

Here is the first script data_converter.py which fits all images to one the same size and make some distortions. Afterwards, the script writes each images into the binary files with its label - [image_label_byte, image_converted_to_bytearray]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import random


def __resize_and_crop(img, size):
    shape = np.shape(img)
    if len(shape) == 3:
        h = shape[0]
        w = shape[1]
        if h < w:
            scale = h / size
            shape = (size, int(w / scale))
        else:
            scale = w / size
            shape = (int(h / scale), size)
        img = cv2.resize(img, shape)
        h = shape[0]
        w = shape[1]
        if h < w:
            delta = (w - size) / 2
            img = img[delta:(w - delta), 0:size]
        else:
            delta = (h - size) / 2
            img = img[0:size, delta:(h - delta)]
        return img
    else:
        print("Wrong shape!")
        return None


def __randomly_rotate(img):
    degrees = [90, 180, 270]
    size = img.shape[0]
    rotation_matrix = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((size / 2, size / 2), degrees[random.randint(0, 2)], 1.0)
    return cv2.warpAffine(img, rotation_matrix, (size, size))


def preprocess_image(root_folder, outputpath, size, distort):
    """
    Converts images from 'root_folder' into a byte array where first byte is
    a label 0 for cats and 1 for dogs. Afterwards, writes converted images into
    a file with 'outputpath'.
    """
    with open(outputpath, 'w') as output_file:
        output_file.write('')
    counter = 0
    with open(outputpath, 'br+') as output_file:
        for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(root_folder):
            print(len(filenames))
            for fname in filenames:
                if fname.endswith('.jpg'):
                    img_path = os.path.join(root, fname)
                    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
                    resized = __resize_and_crop(img, size)
                    label = 0 if fname.split('.')[0] == 'cat' else 1
                    images = [resized]
                    if distort:
                        images.append(__randomly_rotate(resized))
                        images.append(cv2.flip(resized, 1))
                    for indx, i in enumerate(images):
                        b_arr = bytearray([label]) + bytearray(np.array(i).flatten())
                        if len(b_arr) == size * size * 3 + 1:
                            output_file.write(b_arr)
                            counter += 1
                        if counter % 1000 == 0:
                            print(counter)
    print("Total images: " + str(counter))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    preprocess_image('data/train', 'train_batch', 64, True)
```

Second script is cnn_input which provide feeding the data to a CNN:

```
import tensorflow as tf

IMAGE_SIZE = 64
NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_TRAIN = 50000
NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_EVAL = 10000


def read_image(filename_queue):
    class ImageRecord(object):
        pass

    result = ImageRecord()

    label_bytes = 1
    result.height = IMAGE_SIZE
    result.width = IMAGE_SIZE
    result.depth = 3
    image_bytes = result.height * result.width * result.depth
    record_bytes = label_bytes + image_bytes

    reader = tf.FixedLengthRecordReader(record_bytes=record_bytes)
    result.key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

    record_bytes = tf.decode_raw(value, tf.uint8)

    result.label = tf.cast(tf.slice(record_bytes, [0], [label_bytes]), tf.int32)

    depth_major = tf.reshape(tf.slice(record_bytes, [label_bytes], [image_bytes]),
                         [result.depth, result.height, result.width])
    result.uint8image = tf.transpose(depth_major, [1, 2, 0])

    return result


def _generate_image_and_label_batch(image, label, min_queue_examples,
                                batch_size, shuffle):
    num_preprocess_threads = 4
    if shuffle:
        images, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
            [image, label],
            batch_size=batch_size,
            num_threads=num_preprocess_threads,
            capacity=min_queue_examples + 3 * batch_size,
            min_after_dequeue=min_queue_examples)
    else:
        images, label_batch = tf.train.batch(
            [image, label],
            batch_size=batch_size,
            num_threads=num_preprocess_threads,
            capacity=min_queue_examples + 3 * batch_size)
        print("Finished shuffle batch")
    return images, label_batch


def inputs(data_files, batch_size, train):
    for f in data_files:
        if not tf.gfile.Exists(f):
            raise ValueError('Failed to find file: ' + f)
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(data_files)

    image = read_image(filename_queue)
    reshaped_image = tf.cast(image.uint8image, tf.float32)

    if train:
        reshaped_image = tf.image.random_brightness(reshaped_image, max_delta=63)
        reshaped_image = tf.image.random_contrast(reshaped_image, lower=0.2, upper=1.8)
        reshaped_image = tf.image.per_image_whitening(reshaped_image)

    num_examples_per_epoch = NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_TRAIN if train else NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_EVAL
    min_fraction_of_examples_in_queue = 0.2

    min_queue_examples = int(num_examples_per_epoch *
                         min_fraction_of_examples_in_queue)
    print('Filling queue with %d images. '
      'This will take a few minutes.' % min_queue_examples)
    # Generate a batch of images and labels by building up a queue of examples.
    return _generate_image_and_label_batch(reshaped_image, image.label,
                                       min_queue_examples, batch_size,
                                       shuffle=train)
```

And the third one is the CNN itslef:

```
import datetime
import tensorflow as tf
import time
import numpy as np
import os

import cnn_input


tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('batch_size', 256, """Number of images to process in a batch.""")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('train_dir', 'train/',
                       """Directory where to write event logs """
                       """and checkpoint.""")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('max_steps', 60000, '')

FLAGS = tf.flags.FLAGS


def __conv2d(x, W, b, strides=1):
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, strides, strides, 1], padding='SAME')
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, b)
    return tf.nn.relu(x)


def __maxpool2d(x, k=2):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, k, k, 1], strides=[1, k, k, 1],
                      padding='SAME')


def cnn(x):
    with tf.variable_scope('conv1'):
        w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 3, 64]))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64]))
    conv1 = __conv2d(x, w, b)

    pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv1, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                     padding='SAME', name='pool1')

    norm1 = tf.nn.lrn(pool1, 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75,
                  name='norm1')

    with tf.variable_scope('conv2'):
        w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 64, 64]))
        b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64]))
        conv2 = __conv2d(norm1, w, b)

    # norm2
    norm2 = tf.nn.lrn(conv2, 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75,
                  name='norm2')
    # pool2
    pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(norm2, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1],
                       strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name='pool2')

    # local3
    with tf.variable_scope('local3') as scope:
        reshape = tf.reshape(pool2, [FLAGS.batch_size, -1])
        dim = reshape.get_shape()[1].value
        w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([dim, 1024], stddev=0.04))
        b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024]))
        local3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshape, w) + b, name=scope.name)

    # local4
    with tf.variable_scope('local4') as scope:
        w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, 192], stddev=0.04))
        b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([192]))
        local4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(local3, w) + b, name=scope.name)

    # softmax, i.e. softmax(WX + b)
    with tf.variable_scope('softmax_linear') as scope:
        w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([192, 1], stddev=1 / 192.0))
        b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]))
        softmax_linear = tf.add(tf.matmul(local4, w), b, name=scope.name)
    return tf.nn.sigmoid(softmax_linear)


def loss(predicted, labels):
    labels = tf.cast(labels, tf.float32)
    c = tf.nn.l2_loss(predicted - labels)
    tf.add_to_collection('losses', c)
    return tf.add_n(tf.get_collection('losses'), name='total_loss')


def optimize(total_loss, global_step):
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.005)
    optimizer.minimize(total_loss, global_step)
    return tf.no_op()


def train():
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
        images, labels = cnn_input.inputs(['data/train_batch'], tf.app.flags.FLAGS.batch_size, True)
        predicted = cnn(images)
        cost = loss(predicted, labels)

        train_op = optimize(cost, global_step)
        saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables())

        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(predicted - tf.cast(labels, tf.float32)))

        init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

        sess = tf.Session()
        sess.run(init)

        tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess)

        for step in range(FLAGS.max_steps):
            start_time = time.time()
            _, loss_value, acc = sess.run([train_op, cost, accuracy])
                duration = time.time() - start_time

        assert not np.isnan(loss_value), 'Model diverged with loss = NaN'

        if step % 100 == 0:
            num_examples_per_step = FLAGS.batch_size
            examples_per_sec = num_examples_per_step / duration
            sec_per_batch = float(duration)

            format_str = ('%s: step %d, accuracy = %.2f, loss = %.2f (%.1f examples/sec; %.3f '
                          'sec/batch)')
            print(format_str % (datetime.datetime.now(), step, acc, loss_value,
                                examples_per_sec, sec_per_batch))
        if step % 1000 == 0 or (step + 1) == FLAGS.max_steps:
            checkpoint_path = os.path.join(FLAGS.train_dir, 'model.ckpt')
            saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path, global_step=step)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    train()
```

Comment: check your input and make sure its correct, change your learning rate if it is high the model won't learn, check your regularization parameter if you have any if it is big the model won't learn anything. Also make sure your labels are correct.

Comment: @Afshin does the code look ok from your point of view?

Comment: don't have any experience with tensorflow or cnn, just worked with lasagne/mlp. So difficult to say if it's the code. You can try another classifier (e.g. one of scikit-learn's) to make sure your input and output are correct.